# ReactiveAsyncCommand with CanExecute = null results in CanExecute always being false

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

This question is related to a question I posted some time ago ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847742/reactiveui-command-binding)).

I am using a `ReactiveAsyncCommand` in the following way:

```
LoadTickets = new ReactiveAsyncCommand(null, 0, RxApp.DeferredScheduler);

LoadTickets.RegisterAsyncFunction(x => loadTickets())
        .ToProperty(this, x => x.Tickets);

Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), RxApp.DeferredScheduler)
        .InvokeCommand(LoadTickets);

LoadTickets.Execute(null); //initial load
```

So, each 10 seconds I would like to call a command which will pipe the results of a function to a List.

However, after the initial `Execute`, each subsequent time, the `CanExecute` on the command is false. I checked that using:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), RxApp.DeferredScheduler)
                        .Subscribe(_ =>
                         Debug.WriteLine("Can execute in timer " + LoadTickets.CanExecute(null))
                              );
```

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

Found it, something that I overlooked:

```
LoadTickets = new ReactiveAsyncCommand(null, 1, RxApp.DeferredScheduler);
```

I had set the maximumConcurrent to 0 which probably explains why the command's `CanExecute` was always false.